# How load dynamic component in class-based vue component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have two components which are trying to load dynamicly using object map.

1. Info (options-based)
2. SearchBar (class-based)

It works for options-based, but when i trying to load similar class-based component, i getting `_currentTab` is `undefined`. I tryed to use `new SearchBar`, but this too not working.

Vuex Module.

```js
export default class Sidebar extends VuexModule {
    private _currentTab: object = tabs.SearchBar;
}
```

Tabs map

```js
import SearchBar from "@/components/Tabs/SearchBar.vue";
import Info      from "@/components/Tabs/Info.vue";

export default {
    SearchBar : SearchBar,
    Info      : Info,
}
```

Sidebar Component

```html
<div class="tab">
    <component v-bind:is="currentTab"></component>
</div>
```

```js
import {Component, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import {mapGetters}     from 'vuex';

@Component({
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            currentTab    : 'currentTab',
        }),
    },
})
export default class Sidebar extends Vue {

}
```

Info Component (options-based)

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {}
    },
}
```

SearchBar Component (class-based)

```js
import {Component, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import {mapActions}     from 'vuex';

@Component
export default class SearchBar extends Vue {

}
```

Comment: It's currentTab in one place and _currentTab in another.  Did you debug tabs object in VuexModule? The code misses some parts and lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .  There may be circular dependency, it's a common reason for things to be undefined while they are expected not to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamic import I use :

```
  components: {
    History: () => import("./History"),
    MenuCardRight: () => import("@/components/MenuCardRight")
  },
```